Rider on macOS gives malicious software every time it builds
I am working one a Rider project on macOS Sonoma.  Every time I compile and run my app, macOS pops up with this.

go to settings/security, say yea, allow, and everything runs.  until i recompile the binary, then the whole process over again.  I can't find anything anywhere to tell macOS, hey, im working here?

I don't know much about MacOS/the app that is flagging it as malicious software, but there is likely a way to ignore/whitelist the project/output folder that contains the "malicious" software.

You can try bypassing the quarantine for the folder where your project is by using the following command:
sudo xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine <path to the solution folder> 

If you don't have permission to run it with sudo on the folder, I think you can also create a post build event only for the debug folder.
